# Can no longer boot from the default kernel

Tags: boot, 22.04

Recently I found I couldn't restart google-chrome after I had tried to shut it down so I rebooted.  The computer didn't shut down properly so I powered off and back on again.  When the computer tried to come back I got to the grub prompt and pressed Enter as I always do but then the screen went blank and the system never came up. I tried another few times and the same thing happened.

There are two options for the kernel in my grub

```
5.15.0-53-generic
5.15.0-52-generic
```

with the first one being the default.

Out of desperation I tried the second one and this works!

What can I do to fix the 5.15.0-53-generic option?  I don't know what broke it.

```
df -h;df -i
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.4G  2.2M  1.4G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       439G  150G  267G  36% /
tmpfs           6.9G   64M  6.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.4G  2.5M  1.4G   1% /run/user/1000
Filesystem       Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs           1782728    1691  1781037    1% /run
/dev/sda2      29278208 1482490 27795718    6% /
tmpfs           1782728     117  1782611    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1782728       4  1782724    1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1             0       0        0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs            356545     173   356372    1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Check of all  packages are correct installed. If you have any closed source modules on your system like nvidia or other check with `dkms status` Make sure you have enough place ond inodes free if you have an own /boot filesystem.

Comment: @nobody I don't have nvidia but how do I do the check you mentioned?

Comment: nvidia was only an example. Please [edit]  your question `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`  and `df -h;df -i` and `dkms status` if your system says dkms not found forget the last one. It could also be some kind of problem with the kernel itself.

Comment: @nobody dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'  gives Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=============================================-=======================================-============-================================================================================

Comment: I would remove the not running kernel  and wait for the next one.

Comment: @nobody The kernel ran for a long time happily so I must have corrupted something.

Comment: Then try to reinstall the packages,